# Mapping shipping routes

Tags: routes, google-earth

To start off, I have only a basic understanding of GIS software (qGIS mainly), and mainly use GE Pro to create visualizations. I apologize in advance, as this may be a very basic question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to display the vessel routes/tracks in Google Earth (as an overlay) for further analysis. My data set is quite large, with 67000 rows in excel containing (Lat, Lon, Ship Name, Date, Time).

My main question is this: How do I create lines between each placemark to visualize the route a vessel is taking? Because my data contains movements on a number of vessels, each vessel would have its on individual path.

For reference, here's one map that has routes plotted out:

[image: map with routes plotted out]
<sub>(source: [schwehr.org](http://schwehr.org/blog/attachments/2008-12/vos-vessel-tracks-in-ge.png))</sub>

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) Read the kml-tutorial https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut (or at least the part on the definition of lines).

2) Export your sets of coordinates from excel e.g. into a csv file, formatted in a useful way.

3) Use any programming language, which can generate a simple kml file based on your csv file. A python script of bash script should be sufficient.